# Trouble when changing pixel data with alpha on png on iphone --okay on simulator

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to change the color of the pixels (lighten or darken) without changing the value of the alpha channel using CGDataProviderCopyData. I leave every 4th databyte untouched. It work fine of the iphone simulator, however on the real thing the alpha goes white as I increase the values of the other pixels. I've tried changing just the first byte, or the second, or the third. Does anybody have any idea what is going on?
The basic code is borrowed from Jorge. I like this simple approach --I'm new to this. But I want to make it work with png images with some transparency.

here is most of the code  by Jorge :

```
CFDataRef CopyImagePixels(CGImageRef inImage){
    return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
}

CGImageRef img=originalImage.CGImage;
    CFDataRef dataref=CopyImagePixels(img);
    UInt8 *data=(UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(dataref);
    int length=CFDataGetLength(dataref);
    for(int index=0;index<length;index+=4){
        // BRIGHTNESS
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(data[index+i]+value<0){
                data[index+i]=0;
            }else{
                if(data[index+i]+value>255){
                    data[index+i]=255;
                }else{
                    data[index+i]+=value;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    size_t width=CGImageGetWidth(img);
    size_t height=CGImageGetHeight(img);
    size_t bitsPerComponent=CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(img);
    size_t bitsPerPixel=CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(img);
    size_t bytesPerRow=CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace=CGImageGetColorSpace(img);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo=CGImageGetBitmapInfo(img);
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask(img);
    NSLog(@"bitmapinfo:  %d",bitmapInfo);
    CFDataRef newData=CFDataCreate(NULL,data,length);
    CGDataProviderRef provider=CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(newData);
    CGImageRef newImg=CGImageCreate(width,height,bitsPerComponent,bitsPerPixel,bytesPerRow,colorspace,bitmapInfo,provider,NULL,true,kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    [iv setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImg]];
    CGImageRelease(newImg);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the byte order is "optimized" on the iPhone but not on the simulator. Details here http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html

Comment: Thanks for your insight. --- just registered-  I originally asked the question...

I guess that the iphone adjusts the png's for faster display by pre-multiplying the alpha channel.  I got decent results by multiplying all the colors by the alpha channel /128 --I don't know why 128, but it seemed to work well.
Thanks again for your input.  I would give your answer a positive review, but because I'm new here it won't let me.